# Cordova iOS Build Fails in Release Mode

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, taco

I'm using Visual Studio to develop a multiplatform Cordova app. When I do an iOS build in debug mode, it works correctly, using the remote build system to connect to a Mac computer.

However, when it do a build in release mode, it claims to finish successfully, but does not produce any .iap file. After investigating, I found that it doesn't contact the remote build server at all. How can I fix this? Here's a log of the build:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: DewdropClient, Configuration: Release iOS ------
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 4.2.1 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.28
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Cordova tools 6.2.0 already installed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\bld\iOS\Release
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\bin\iOS\Release
1>  ------    buildCommand: prepare
1>  ------    platform: iOS
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: ios
1>  ------    configuration: Release
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Release
1>  ------    projectName: DewdropClient
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\Reuben\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------ Platform ios already exists
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  ------ Currently installed plugins: cordova-plugin-actionsheet@2.2.2,cordova-plugin-compat@1.0.0,cordova-plugin-device@1.1.1,cordova-plugin-dialogs@1.1.1,cordova-plugin-geolocation@2.2.0,cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@1.3.0,cordova-plugin-network-information@1.0.1,cordova-plugin-statusbar@1.0.1,cordova-plugin-vibration@2.1.0,cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.0.0,cordova-plugin-x-toast@2.4.2,uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator@3.1.1
1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins: cordova-plugin-compat,cordova-plugin-actionsheet
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins: cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.0.0,cordova-plugin-statusbar@1.0.1,cordova-plugin-dialogs@1.1.1,cordova-plugin-network-information@1.0.1,cordova-plugin-vibration@2.1.0,cordova-plugin-device@1.1.1
1>  ------ Preparing platform: ios
1>  No scripts found for hook "before_build".
1>  No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
1>  Checking config.xml for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
1>  Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in ios platform
1>  No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in ios platform. Continuing...
1>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "ios"
1>  Wrote out iOS Bundle Identifier to "io.reuben.dodrop"
1>  Wrote out iOS Bundle Version to "1.0.0"
1>  iOS Product Name has not changed (still "DoDrop")
1>  Copying icon from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\icons\ios\icon-60.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\icon-60.png
1>  Copying icon from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\icons\ios\icon-60-2x.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\icon-60@2x.png
1>  Copying icon from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\icons\ios\icon-60-3x.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\icon-60@3x.png
1>  Copying icon from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\icons\ios\icon-76.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\icon-76.png
1>  Copying icon from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\icons\ios\icon-76-2x.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\icon-76@2x.png
1>  Copying icon from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\icons\ios\icon-small.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\icon-small.png
1>  Copying icon from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\icons\ios\icon-small-2x.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\icon-small@2x.png
1>  Copying icon from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\icons\ios\icon-40.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\icon-40.png
1>  Copying icon from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\icons\ios\icon-40-2x.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\icon-40@2x.png
1>  Copying icon from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\icons\ios\icon-57.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\icon.png
1>  Copying icon from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\icons\ios\icon-57-2x.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\icon@2x.png
1>  Copying icon from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\icons\ios\icon-72.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\icon-72.png
1>  Copying icon from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\icons\ios\icon-72-2x.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\icon-72@2x.png
1>  Copying icon from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\icons\ios\icon-50.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\icon-50.png
1>  Copying icon from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\icons\ios\icon-50-2x.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\icon-50@2x.png
1>  Copying splash from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Default~iphone.png
1>  Copying splash from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Default@2x~iphone.png
1>  Copying splash from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-portrait.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Default-Portrait~ipad.png
1>  Copying splash from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png
1>  Copying splash from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-landscape.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Default-Landscape~ipad.png
1>  Copying splash from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
1>  Copying splash from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-568h-2x.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Default-568h@2x~iphone.png
1>  Copying splash from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Default-667h.png
1>  Copying splash from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Default-736h.png
1>  Copying splash from C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png to C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\DewdropClient\DewdropClient\platforms\ios\DoDrop\Images.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Default-Landscape-736h.png
1>  updated project successfully
1>  No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
1>  Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, using the "Build Solution" button does not work, but clicking the button with the green arrow labeled "Remote Device" does work in release mode.